# I tried using UserDefaults for a score not to reset to zero every time it opens but it doesn't work

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to create an in-app currency system in my game. To do this I tried using UserDefaults in order for said currency to not reset to zero every time I close the app and reopen or switch to a different viewController and switch back. However, it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var notesScore = 0

@IBAction func IncreaseNotes(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    notesScore = notesScore + 1
    notesLabel.text = String(notesScore)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = colors.themeBlue
    notesLabel.textColor = colors.white

    var notesScoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard

    if (notesScoreDefault.value(forKey: "notesScore")  != nil)
    {
        notesScore = notesScoreDefault.value(forKey: "notesScore") as! NSInteger
        notesLabel.text = NSString(format: "Notes: %i", notesScore) as String
    }
```

Comment: Where do you make any attempt to save the score to `UserDefaults`?

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)`. Please look at the documentation for UserDefaults and use the proper method to get data from UserDefaults.

Comment: @rmaddy notesScoreDefault. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you don't do anything. You make no attempt to save the latest score to UserDefaults.

Comment: @rmaddy How would I fix this?

Comment: You need to add code in the proper place that stores your score in UserDefaults.

Comment: @rmaddy How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store score when it is being changed. For example, when you are increasing the score, you can store that into `userdefaults`.

```
@IBAction func IncreaseNotes(_ sender: UIButton) {
    notesScore = notesScore + 1
    notesLabel.text = String(notesScore)
    // Saving score.
    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.notesScore, forKey: "notesScore")
}
```

Now in `viewDidLoad`, you can retrieve that score as below,

```
let score = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "notesScore")
notesLabel.text = String(score)
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks dude! It works now! Just one question if I wanted to display it in another view controller the same way. How would I do it?

Comment: You can get score value anywhere in your app using `let score = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "notesScore")
`

Comment: There is no need to update `UserDefaults` on a background queue.

Comment: @rmaddy When setting something very frequently, it blocks the main thread but yeah it looks fine in normal usage. Inconsistency between saving in background and retrieving in main thread could be an issue.

Comment: Wait. Whats the 'DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async' for?

Comment: This is just to keep the set value operation on the background thread. As it might cause confusion for  beginners so i'll remove this because it is not required in normal updates to `UserDefaults`.

Comment: There is a nice tutorial regarding DispatchQueue if you want to learn more here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2

Comment: @Kamran Thank you for explaining it to me. I want to learn more

Comment: @Mattk90 Thank you for the resource I'll be sure to look into it. I'm always looking to learn something you know

Comment: @Mattk90 shared a very good link that will surely add value to your skillset. Give it a read.

Comment: One more thing. Sorry for the bother. When I go back now and set the var score to 50. It stays zero from before. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is my updated code

    var notesScore = 50
    

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = colors.themeBlue
        notesLabel.textColor = colors.white
        
        let notesScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "notesScore")
        notesLabel.text = "Notes: " + String(notesScore)

Comment: Sorry it turned out pretty bad in my previous comment

Comment: Remember, to get a value from the `UserDefaults`, you have to save that first. Did you save 50 in `UserDefaults`? No, so you will not get 50. When you assigned `notesScore` variable with default value of 50 it means you should save 50 before accessing that value from `UserDefaults`.

Comment: If I wanted to update it in another view controller. Would I have to redeclare notesScore?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184206/discussion-between-kamran-and-alex-tnsescu).

Comment: @Kamran I thing I found the problem. I messaged you in chat

Answer (score 0):

So I'd generally recommend you to write a UserdefaultsHelper.swift class where you store all your userdefaults in and can keep track.

It should look for example something like this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class UserDefaultsHelper {

    static var notesScore: Int? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notesScore") as? Int
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "notesScore")
        }
    }
}
```

After that anywhere in your App you could access that value just by calling:

```
UserDefaultsHelper.notesScore
```

This is an optional, so next time you need it and maybe even are unsure if it exists you can call in a viewDidLoad for exmaple:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let notesScore = UserDefaultsHelper.notesScore {
        // Do what you want with it here
    }
}
```

And then add something to it or do what you want. I store userIDs or pushTokens like that for example. For future Userdefaults you can just add it to the UserdefaultsHelper.swift

> Edit: Example

Regarding your question in the comments. If you want to increment it by 5. You can do it like this:

```
if let existingNotesScore = UserDefaultsHelper.notesScore {
    UserDefaultsHelper.notesScore = existingNotesScore + 5
}
```

Explanation: With the "if let" you safely check if there is something saved in the Userdefaults in the variable notesScore, if yes it goes inside the {} and you can access the value in existingNotesScore. Then you just override the value in Userdefaults with the existing one + 5

Comment: How would I set the score to go up increments of 5 using UserDefaults?

Comment: @AlexTănăsescu I edited my answer with a code example how to increment it by 5. I hope that helps. Feel free to mark it as the correct solution then! :)

Comment: what about if I didn't want to make it part of the class?

Comment: You mean accessing in globally or how is that now inside a class? Usually you would have to call it inside a class to make certain actions on it?